# Open new Tab window in Radio Button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

please anyone can help me I am stuck in radio buttons.
when user click on submit button under the radio buttons they should be redirected into new window like target="_blank"

please help me if there is any solution available.

then I change window.location.href
two window.open the code is not working properly

```js
function getCheckedValue(radioObj) {
if(!radioObj)
    return "";
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined)
    if(radioObj.checked)
        return radioObj.value;
    else
        return "";
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    if(radioObj[i].checked) {
        return radioObj[i].value;
    }
}
return "";
}

// set the radio button with the given value as being checked
// do nothing if there are no radio buttons
// if the given value does not exist, all the radio buttons
// are reset to unchecked
function setCheckedValue(radioObj, newValue) {
if(!radioObj)
    return;
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined) {
    radioObj.checked = (radioObj.value == newValue.toString());
    return;
}
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    radioObj[i].checked = false;
    if(radioObj[i].value == newValue.toString()) {
        radioObj[i].checked = true;
    }
}
}
```

```css
input[type=radio] {
    -webkit-appearance: radio;
    -O-appearance: radio;
    -moz-appearance: radio;
    opacity:1;
}

#header .bottom-header.blog h1 {
    font-size: 64px;
 color: red
}

input[type=radio]:hover + label {
border: solid 1px white; padding: 5px; border-radius: 1px;
border-color : red;
color : red;
opacity:1;

}  

input[type=radio]:checked + label {
border: solid 2px white; padding: 5px; border-radius: 1px;
border-color : red;
color : red;
opacity:1;
}

input[type=text] {
font-weight:bold;
}
input[type=text]:hover {
}
input[type=email]:hover {
}
```

```html
<form name="radioExampleForm" method="get" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
<p>&nbsp;<label for="number0"><input type="radio" value="http://www.google.com" name="number"     id="number0"> Zero</label></br>
&nbsp;<label for="number1"><input type="radio" value="http://www.ebay.com" name="number" id="number1"> One</label></br>
&nbsp;<label for="number2"><input type="radio" value="http://www.gamestop.com" name="number" id="number2"> Two</label></br>
</p>
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href = (getCheckedValue(document.forms['radioExampleForm'].elements['number']));" value="Buy Now">

</form>
```

Comment: `onclick="window.open(getCheckedValue(document.forms['radioExampleForm'].elements['number']))"` replace your `onclick` method with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `window.open(url, '_blank')` which will open the url in new tab. Again I would say opening in new tab will get certainly get struck by a popup blocker. I would recommend you using an anchor tag with `target="_blank"` in place of button (and change `a` tag's `href` in `onchange` of radio button) which will not get blocked by a popup blocker

```js
function getCheckedValue(radioObj) {
if(!radioObj)
    return "";
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined)
    if(radioObj.checked)
        return radioObj.value;
    else
        return "";
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    if(radioObj[i].checked) {
        return radioObj[i].value;
    }
}
return "";
}

// set the radio button with the given value as being checked
// do nothing if there are no radio buttons
// if the given value does not exist, all the radio buttons
// are reset to unchecked
function setCheckedValue(radioObj, newValue) {
if(!radioObj)
    return;
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined) {
    radioObj.checked = (radioObj.value == newValue.toString());
    return;
}
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    radioObj[i].checked = false;
    if(radioObj[i].value == newValue.toString()) {
        radioObj[i].checked = true;
    }
}
}
```

```css
input[type=radio] {
    -webkit-appearance: radio;
    -O-appearance: radio;
    -moz-appearance: radio;
    opacity:1;
}

#header .bottom-header.blog h1 {
    font-size: 64px;
 color: red
}

input[type=radio]:hover + label {
border: solid 1px white; padding: 5px; border-radius: 1px;
border-color : red;
color : red;
opacity:1;

}  

input[type=radio]:checked + label {
border: solid 2px white; padding: 5px; border-radius: 1px;
border-color : red;
color : red;
opacity:1;
}

input[type=text] {
font-weight:bold;
}
input[type=text]:hover {
}
input[type=email]:hover {
}
```

```html
<form name="radioExampleForm" method="get" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
<p>&nbsp;<label for="number0"><input type="radio" value="http://www.google.com" name="number"     id="number0"> Zero</label></br>
&nbsp;<label for="number1"><input type="radio" value="http://www.ebay.com" name="number" id="number1"> One</label></br>
&nbsp;<label for="number2"><input type="radio" value="http://www.gamestop.com" name="number" id="number2"> Two</label></br>
</p>
<input type="button" onclick="window.open(getCheckedValue(document.forms['radioExampleForm'].elements['number']), '_blank');" value="Buy Now">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below script to do your task

```
    $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
        var numbers = document.getElementsByName('number');
        var num_value;
        for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
            if(numbers[i].checked){
                num_value = numbers[i].value;
                // alert(num_value);
                window.open(num_value, '_blank');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can just remove other script and use the above. All you need to do is on clicking the button, get the value of the selected radio button and use window.open() to open the url in newtab. And hope this works for you..